# System time in QNX system suddenly increases/decreases a few minutes. Why does this happen?

Tags: operating-system, qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

Was the system performing a time update?

Is there a way to prohibit these sudden time changes?

I use CLOCK_MONOTONIC in my program to avoid the impact of these sudden system time changes.
However, the third-party library I'm using could not work correctly when a sudden time change happen.

If provide documentation about the QNX system time update mechanism, I would greatly appreciate it.